# Direct2D and printing

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, direct2d

I have some graphics that are being rendered using Direct2D/DirectWrite (from C++), and now I need to print this. There is exactly one Microsoft example for printing from Direct2D (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct2D-Printing-From-be62d249) but this uses something called the 'XPS print API' for which MSDN says "[The XPS Print API is not supported and may be altered or unavailable in the future. Client applications should use the Print Document Package API instead.]".

Okay fine so I look up that API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448418(v=vs.85).aspx) but that provides 0 examples, let alone something that says how to use it with Direct2D.

So my questions are:

- How am I supposed to print from desktop apps nowadays? There are a bunch of different API's but no guidance on what the difference is or when one should use what.
- Is there an example somewhere on how to use whatever is the recommended way to print?
- Are there any other resources on Direct2D and printing besides the one MSDN sample I linked above? From searching online, I'd say that I'm the first person ever to even look at these APIs...

Comment: couple thoughts off the top of my head: 1) look how chrome(ium) prints ? Maybe there's something useful there. 2) take a screenshot and print the resulting jpeg/png/whatever ? or even use a pdf library and save the image as pdf to print.

Comment: @xyious The first suggestion is no good. Chrome's source code is very large and very complicated, only a small portion of it relates to WinAPI. It's not meant to be a learning tool of some kind.

Comment: I don't understand. The sample you linked to *does* use the Print Document Package API (e.g. the `IPrintDocumentPackageTarget` interface).

Comment: @IInspectable that was actually part of my confusion - it seemed to me like the example uses a mix of both. But after looking again, I'm not sure anymore why I thought that, maybe I was mixing up similar-looking interface names.

Comment: @xyious Thanks, looking at Chrome (which isn't that hard), it seems that they just copied the pertinent parts from that same example, too. So I get the impression that the best way to go about it is to refactor the example code into something more generic, and use that as a helper class, rather than trying to build up my own code from the ground up - because there's a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: The D2DPrintingFromDesktopApps sample doesn't actually use the XPS Print API. But it is true that the XPS Print API is marked as deprecated in the MS online documentation.